# python : convert string to c_ubyte_Array_8

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I have a c++ application which writes blocks of `unsigned char` data. So I would be writing `unsigned char data[8]`.

Now, I am using python (read `ctypes` functionality in python), to read and buffer it in my tool for further processing.

**Problem**
When I read the data from file and break it down into chunks of 8, all the resultant data is in string format.I have the following structure

```
class MyData(Union):
     _fields_=[ ("data",8 * c_ubytes), ("overlap", SelfStructure) ]
```

Now, I am trying to pass the data as follows

```
  dataObj = MyData(str[0:8])
```

It throws an error, `expected c_ubyte_Array_8 instance, got str`. I think I need to convert `string` to `array of size 8 of c_ubyte`. Tried with `bytearray` but did not succeed. Please let me know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(ctypes.c_ubyte * 8)(*[ctypes.c_ubyte(ord(c)) for c in str[:8]])
```